# Assign the size and elements of multi dimensional string array dynamically

Tags: java, android, arrays, listview, gridview

I'm trying to achieve the dynamic grid view with titles/suppuration, for this i got the reference from this [link](https://github.com/velos/SectionedGrid) (this is the studio project [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u1yuqndzyelhub2/SectionedGrid.zip?dl=0)). In this reference project i'm not able to **update the multi dimensional String array dynamically**

**Multi dimensional String array Code**

```
AUTHORS = new String[] { "Roberto Bolao",
  "David Mitchell", "Haruki Murakami", "Thomas Pynchon" };
BOOKS = new String[][] {
  { "The Savage Detectives", "2666" },
  { "Ghostwritten", "number9dream", "Cloud Atlas",
    "Black Swan Green", "The Thousand Autumns of Jacob de Zoet" },
  { "A Wild Sheep Chase",
  ... }};
```

**Notes:**

1. I have updated the `AUTHORS` array dynamically but i'm not able update and define the size of `BOOKS` array dynamically
2. Please check the studio project which i attached here because we have to update the multi dimensional array (`BOOKS`) with help of normal array (`Authors`) (If you run the project means you will get the clear view about my question)

Comment: Please do not post any links to the projects. 
Instead of that, put the Minimal Complete and Verifiable Question -> http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Ya i supposed to post the only code which is related to my question but i posted the project here because it may helpful for some other users (Actually original link not contained whole project so i have implemented the some in my project). I hope every one can understand my concern..

Comment: jakubbialkowski is saying that you need to post the specific code you're having a problem with in the question itself. All you've posted are arrays. That tells us nothing about how you're trying to update them, and you can't expect us to download and run your entire project, and then guess as to where exactly you're having the issue. Also, when those links go dead in the future, this question, as is, won't be of much help to anyone else.

Answer (score 1):

Just go one step further: when your requirement is to deal with **dynamic** number of elements; then use Java's [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) interface resp. one of its implementation classes for your work.

Arrays in Java are not dynamic. The only thing you can do after an array was created is to **change** the content of a given array slot. Yes, when you have two-dim arrays, which is actually an array filled with other arrays, you can "dynamically" put in new arrays ... but again: that is simply inconvenient, cumbersome and error-prone.

Comment: Thnq for your answer. I'll do according to your suggestion and let you know

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to over allocate the array to give room for further expansions. However this will basically give you a naive implementation of a [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html), so preferably a List could be used instead to avoid extra work (or more accurately any of the concrete implementations). In return for relieving you of a lot of work, these classes will also provide better functionality and be more stable.